# Maintain image aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="header">
                <h1 class="text-muted">jQuery Basic Slider</h1>
            </div>

            <div id="slider">
                <ul class="slides">
                    <li class="slide slide1">slide1</li>
                    <li class="slide slide2">slide2</li>
                    <li class="slide slide3">slide3</li>
                    <li class="slide slide4">slide4</li>
                    <li class="slide slide5">slide5</li>
                    <li class="slide slide1">slide1</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#slider {
    width: 720px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#slider .slides {
    display: block;
    width: 6000px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.slide {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/* helper css, since we don't have images */
.slide1 {background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/);}
.slide2 {background: url(http://lorempixel.com/320/180/);}
.slide3 {background: url(http://lorempixel.com/150/300/);}
.slide4 {background: url(http://lorempixel.com/480/220/);}
.slide5 {background: url(http://lorempixel.com/220/200/);}
```

If you take a look at the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/db03t3v6/) you can see that the images aren't maintaining consistent aspect ratios. How can I get the images to all have the same aspect ratio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
.slides{
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specify static parent dimensions and set image to have same dimensions, than it will lose it's aspect ratio. To keep it remove one of dimensions `width: 100%` or `height: 100%`.

Also instead of `background-image` use actual image tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your `#slider` `width` is smaller than `.slide` `width` sum.

If image size is `400px`, `#slider` `width` must be `800px`.